Android: Is there a way to obtain the Frames of a video in real time while it is playing back and being displayed?
I want a way that while a video is playing back, obtain their Frames in Real time so i can then process them, in other words i gotta obtain the frames as bitmaps or similar.
I want something like when you obtain a frame in real time from the camera, when using ProcessCameraProvider and imageAnalyzer like:
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setAnalyzer(backgroundExecutor) { imageProxy ->
                    // imageProxy is the frame it self
                }
            } 

but for a .mp4 video from the gallery instead.
For what I have been reading so far the only ways to obtain the frames of a video are by using either MediaMetadataRetriever or MediaExtractor, but you have to process the whole video at once and obtain all the frames at once too, which is not what I want.
Anyone have any idea?

What does "video is getting reproduced" mean?

Basically reproduce the video with a VideoView or similar and getting the frames in real time while getting reproduced

If you use ExoPlayer, see this and this.

if the video is being reproduced and its in the second 0:03, it should return the bitmap of the frame when the video its in 0:03 (this is an example, the frames can be returned depending on the frameInterval you set)

sounds like OP wants to apply a video filter, or handle the frames in some other way, while it's playing. That surely must be available in plain Android...

I've replaced the "reproduced" with a more recognizable term.
